# Using document.on without event handlers

Tags: jquery

I've run into this several times now, where I wish to use document.on() to manipulate an element, but cannot figure out how to use .on() without an event.

I often use ajax to inject elements into the DOM and frequently need to use document.on() to bind to those injected elements. This works perfectly when I wish to select an element and get at its information.

For example, to attach to a selector via the click event, one writes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mledit', function(event) {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

However, what if I wish to set focus to that element?  How would I do that?  I have tried:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.mledit');
```

and am at a loss as to what else to try.

The reason I need to do this is because at the moment (and I've been here before), the standard `$('.mledit').focus();` is not working. Everything else seems alright, but that one instruction is not. So, I'm wondering if using document.on() is even possible in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$('.mledit')[0].focus();
```

Comment: You know your stuff. Thank you Sime.

Comment: @gibberish Why does *what* work? Are you asking about the `[0]`? If yes then basically when you use a selector in jQuery it returns an array of the matched elements, the `[0]` just says use the first element that is matched.

Comment: @gibberish Elements that can be focused (e.g. `<input>` elements) provide a built-in `.focus()` method for that purpose. So, you use jQuery to find all elements that have a `"mledit"` class, next `[0]` gives you a reference to the first such element (in case there are multiple such elements - trying to focus all of them would not work), and then you just invoke `.focus()` on that element.

Answer (score 3):

[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is meant for binding events, what you are looking for is a way to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) an event on an element.

For example

```
$('.mledit').trigger('focus');
```

At the same time, jQuery also has some convenience/shortcut functions that under the hood will delegate to either .on or .trigger depending on how they are called.

For example you can also use the [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method to trigger focus

```
$('.mledit').focus()
```

Under the hood it really just delegates to the `trigger` method, however if you were to pass in a function it would instead bind that function to the passed in `selecter`.

Just saw your edit.

I'm not sure for certain why your focus event doesn't work when use use `$('.mledit').focus()` but I suspect it's because you are matching more then one element and you can only have focus on one element. To explain when you use a jQuery selector what you get back is a jQuery object, and when you call a method on this returned jQuery object you are actually calling it on all the matched elements.

As a shortcut to accessing the first element of the matched elements array you will often see

```
$('#someSelecter')[0]
```

So in your case to explicitly trigger the focus event on only one (and the first matched) element

You can use

```
$($('.mledit')[0]).focus() r
```

The reason for the double wrapping is because `[0]` returns a regular `DOM` element which doesn't have the jQuery methods on it (the wrapping creates a jQuery object).

Comment: Thanks very much for this great explanation. +1 for the under the hood info.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to set focus.. just do - though if you have more than one you have to specify which one to set focus to using .eq() or []

```
$('.mledit').focus()
```

jQuery also offers the [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method for you to pass in an event to trigger

Answer (score 0):

You would use trigger instead of on.

```
$(SELECTOR).trigger(EVENT_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to trigger event "foo" on elements that match "selector", use this syntax:

```
$('selector').trigger("foo");
```

In your case:

```
$('.mledit').trigger("focus");
```